# VSCode quick import work with ctrl + space, but not with ctrl + . with Vite + React project

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, vite, yarnpkg

as above, project initialized with yarn + vite + react
OS: win 10 pro

This is file structure:

[image]

vite.config.js:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
});
```

jsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es6",
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "@/*": ["src/*"]
        },
    },
    "exclude": ["node_modules"],
}
```

List of extensions:

```
amazonwebservices.aws-toolkit-vscode
Angular.ng-template
burkeholland.simple-react-snippets
bysabi.prettier-vscode-standard
christian-kohler.npm-intellisense
christian-kohler.path-intellisense
dbaeumer.vscode-eslint
donjayamanne.githistory
dsznajder.es7-react-js-snippets
eamodio.gitlens
EditorConfig.EditorConfig
elltg.elltg-npm-script-run
esbenp.prettier-vscode
firefox-devtools.vscode-firefox-debug
formulahendry.code-runner
geddski.macros
GitHub.copilot
Gydunhn.angular-essentials
Gydunhn.javascript-essentials
Gydunhn.typescript-essentials
infeng.vscode-react-typescript
iulian-radu-at.find-unused-exports
johnpapa.angular-essentials
johnpapa.Angular2
johnpapa.pwa-tools
johnpapa.vscode-peacock
johnpapa.winteriscoming
mgmcdermott.vscode-language-babel
Mikael.Angular-BeastCode
ms-python.black-formatter
ms-python.python
ms-python.vscode-pylance
ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl
ms-vscode.cmake-tools
ms-vscode.cpptools
ms-vscode.cpptools-extension-pack
ms-vscode.cpptools-themes
ms-vsliveshare.vsliveshare
natewallace.angular2-inline
nrwl.angular-console
NuclleaR.vscode-extension-auto-import
numso.prettier-standard-vscode
odubuc.mysql-inline-decorator
PKief.material-icon-theme
pmneo.tsimporter
redhat.vscode-commons
redhat.vscode-yaml
steoates.autoimport
stringham.move-ts
TabNine.tabnine-vscode
tombonnike.vscode-status-bar-format-toggle
twxs.cmake
VisualStudioExptTeam.intellicode-api-usage-examples
VisualStudioExptTeam.vscodeintellicode
xabikos.JavaScriptSnippets
```

**What I tried:**

I installed auto import, ES7 React snippets, simple react snippets, tried to load without extensions, tried to move jsconfig.json setup to vite.config.json

It didn't change anything at all

Comment: Rather than dumping us a list of your extensions, tell us the following: Does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the `Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled` command in the command palette)? If not, then do an [extension bisect](//code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to figure out what extension is causing it.

Comment: with that amount of extensions the code should write itself

Comment: @starball yes, I used this option and it happens with Extensions Disabled

Comment: @starball also if you would read my full question you would know. Read section what I tried

Comment: my bad. but info is still missing: you showed what you tried, but didn't say the results of each of those things that you tried.

Comment: you're right, I thought it's obvious, maybe I should be more precise - it didn't change anything at all